# Can one "pickle" meat to make it kosher?

Tags: halacha, meat, kashering-kosherization

Most of the meat koshering processes that I have read say that one should salt the meat and put it on a board to let the blood drain out. Then, you rinse off the salt.

I'm wondering if the salting and rinsing need to be a separate process. Let's say you brine the meat by putting it in a strong salted liquid and the blood gets drawn out in the water. Is this acceptable? Can you also put other spices (e.g. allspice, peppers, etc.) while it is brining? The spices would remain in the water after you take out the meat.

Comment: Where would the blood go if not right back in to the meat?? On the board it drains away

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not necessarily true (but the answer says no to this practice). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis

Comment: @Kazi Word to the wise: don't expect Hilkhot Melicha to match with Metziut in any meaningful way.

Comment: @DoubleAA They are perfectly right, because by adding whatever small quantity of water to the salt, one would decrease the effect of the osmosis. So the concern is that the liquid doesn't come out, not that it goes back.

Comment: @Kazi that's not the concern Halakhically though

Comment: While brining in salt water is not a valid form a kashering, you are allowed to pickle meat in vinegar as a form of kashering., and you can even drink the vinegar you pickled it in afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rambam explicitly forbids this (MT Hilchot [Ma'achalot Assurot 6:11-12](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Foods.6.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> **When meat is salted, it should be salted only in a perforated utensil**,
> using only salt that is as heavy as coarse sand, since the salt that
> is as fine as flour becomes absorbed in the meat and fails to extract
> the blood. Also, one must shake off the salt before rinsing the meat [...] All of the above procedures apply with regard to meat that one must
> cook. For roasting, by contrast, one may salt the meat and roast it
> immediately.

R Elyahu Touger comments ([fn. 39](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968262/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-6.htm#footnote39a968262)): If one salted meat in a utensil that did not have holes, **all the meat lying in the brine is forbidden**.

See also [SA Yoreh Deah 69:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.69.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> We perform the salting **only in a vessel with holes or upon straw or
> shavings or in a diagonal position ensuring that if water was spilled
> onto it, it would flow off immediately**.

and [69:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.69.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> Meat that was salted in a vessel without holes and was left for as
> long as it takes for water to begin boiling is subject to the
> following rules: anything in the tzir is forbidden [and what is out is
> not but the Rema forbids the entire piece]